# Django formset: Unable to to submit formset due to errors

Tags: django, django-forms

Following is my model:

```
class ContentLineConfig(models.Model):
    content_template = models.ForeignKey(ContentTemplate, null=False, verbose_name="Content template")
    line_x_start_cord = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Line start X cordinate")
    line_y_start_cord = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Line start Y cordinate")
    line_x_end_cord = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Line end  X cordinate")
    line_y_end_cord = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Line end Y cordinate")
    line_fill_color = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="WHITE", choices=COLOR_CHOICE,
                                   verbose_name="Line fill color")
    line_width = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Line width")
    archive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Form:

```
class ContentLineConfigForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContentLineConfig
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['id','archive','content_template',]
```

View:

```
class ContentLineConfigView(ModelFormSetView):
    model = ContentLineConfig
    form_class = ContentLineConfigForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('content_templates_list')
    template_name = 'formtemplates/test_formset.html'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.content_template_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return super(ContentLineConfigView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self,form):
        return super(ContentLineConfigView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Template:

```
<div class="container">


    <form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</div>
```

URL:

```
url(r'^ct/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/lines/create/$', 
ContentLineConfigView.as_view(), name='content_line_create')
```

When I am submitting the formset I get the following error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: 
contenttemplates_contentlineconfig.content_template_id
```

But when I see the error page in detail, I see the following:

```
formset <django.forms.formsets.ContentLineConfigFormFormSet object at 0x10821e3d0>
kwargs {'pk': u'1'}
```

Why this error?

Also, If I submit empty formset, I get redirected to success_url, there is not validation happening at all, why are the validations being skipped?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`instance.content_template_id = int(self.kwargs['pk'])`

Was wondering how the `pk` could be char instead of digits!

`url(r'^ct/(?P<pk>\d+)/lines/create/$',`